# What's the difference/advantages between ICriteria and ICriterion in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

Bit of a newbie question as Im getting started with nHibernate.

What's the difference between `NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion` and `NHibernate.ICriteria` classes and which should I use for simple "`where field=value`" type filtering?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An ICriteria is used to represent a query.
You can add ICriterions to this ICriteria to express filters.

For instance:

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Person));

crit.Add (NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Eq("Name", "somename"));
```

Or, as the documentation states:

> ICriterion: An object oriented
>   representation of a query criterion
>   that may be used as a constraint in an
>   ICriteria query
>
> ICriteria: a simplified API for
>   retrieving entities by composing
>   NHibernate.Criterion.Expression
>   objects.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Am just getting a little overloaded at the mo'. Your example makes it clear now.